# ERROR in running chef-client on node

Tags: chef-infra

INFO: Error while reporting run start to Data Collector. URL: https://api.chef.io/organizations/james/data-collector Exception: 404 -- 404 "Not Found"  (This is normal if you do not have Chef Automate)

I'm using windows(2012R2) machine as workstation, and ubuntu(14.04) as node.
Bootstrapping node was completed, I updated one cookbook, I ran chef-client in node, But my recipes were not updated, It throwing above error. What I need to do?
From where(/etc/chef/ or /home/ubuntu/ or /var/ or ??) I need to run this chef-client command?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error itself, this is normal if you aren't using Chef Automate, it's not a fatal error and doesn't hurt Chef at all (other than the data collector subsystem disables itself since it has no server to report to).

Answer (score 0):

1. Please run the chef client in debug mode, it will provide more information: `chef-client -ldebug`
2. Please check chef-client logs and focus on messages flagged with "ERROR"; the "INFO" message above is not the real reason of the failure;
3. I guess the bootstrapped node does not have sufficient permissions to "read" (or "update") objects in the Chef server. This can be fixed using the Chef Server Management web interface: look-up the node with problems, check its permissions tab ("Details" - "Attributes" - "Permissions"): admins, clients, user, nodes..., add the name of the node /client, tick the appropriate permission checkbox: read, write etc.